# Low throughput and packet loss with Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2200 Ethernet controller when accessing WAN

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, atheros

I've recently switched to Linux as primary OS on my main system. I'm experiencing weird problems with the Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2200 Gigabit Ethernet controller though. This Ethernet controller is part of my MSI Z87-G45 gaming motherboard.

**Problem description**
When accessing the public Internet the card caps around 20 to 30 Mbit/s while I've access to a 50Mbit/s connection. Also, when the card caps at this speed I'm experiencing a lot of packet loss.

To give an example: A Steam download caps at 2 to 3MB/s, and when a download is active I experience a lot of packet loss in Mumble (VOIP client) and some other connections tend to drop periodically.

My LAN is capped at 100Mbit/s because of a network switch. But of course, 20 to 30Mbit/s doesn't even come close.

**Additional notes**

- When accessing LAN devices, such as my NAS, the full throughput is used and everything seems to work fine. Thus, this problem only occurs when accessing the public Internet.
- Everything worked fine on my Windows 7 installation, with ~50Mbit/s, and no packet loss or connection drops whatsoever.
- I do only start noticing packet loss when the WAN connection is 'capped', not with usage below 5Mbit/s.
- I didn't manually install any additional drivers. The card worked out of the box with a fresh installation, sort of.

**System information**

```
$ ~> lspci | grep Killer
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)


$ ~> screenfetch -n
 timvisee@AxiomLinux
 OS: Ubuntu 16.10 yakkety
 Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.8.0-34-generic
 Uptime: 19h 3m
 Packages: 2388
 Shell: fish
 Resolution: 3200x1097
 DE: Gnome 
 WM: GNOME Shell
 WM Theme: Adwaita, Adapta-Nokto [GTK2], Adapta-Nokto [GTK3]
 Icon Theme: Papirus-Dark
 Font: Cantarell 11
 CPU: Intel Core i5-4670K CPU @ 3.8GHz
 GPU: GeForce GTX 550 Ti
 RAM: 5480MiB / 15991MiB


$ ~> ip -s link
...
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 44:8a:5b:24:46:50 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    32490908621 22983929 0       0       0       15751   
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    2694939812 14217026 0       0       0       0 
...


$ ~> lspci -v | grep Killer -A11
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at f6100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at d000 [size=128]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [c0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/16 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d8] MSI-X: Enable- Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [180] Device Serial Number ff-24-46-50-44-8a-5b-ff
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx


$ ~> sudo netstat -s | egrep -i 'loss|retran'
    24 segments retransmited
    TCPLossProbes: 23
    TCPLossProbeRecovery: 1
    TCPSynRetrans: 4


$ ~> sudo ping -s 1 -f -c 1000 -w 5 timvisee.com
PING timvisee.com (159.253.1.168) 1(29) bytes of data.
--- timvisee.com ping statistics ---
304 packets transmitted, 157 received, 48% packet loss, time 4990ms
pipe 5, ipg/ewma 16.469/0.000 ms


$ ~> sudo ethtool enp3s0
Settings for enp3s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Current message level: 0x000060e4 (24804)
                   link ifup rx_err tx_err hw wol
    Link detected: yes


$ ~> modinfo alx | grep version
srcversion:     148031F2236BBDAF23DA652
vermagic:       4.8.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

**Packet loss in Mumble**
That the last command shown above states that there are no packet errors and/or drops. Mumble does state something else though. Weird.
[image: Mumble connection status]

---

What is causing this problem? The public Internet connection cap and the packets being dropped. And how can I fix it? Is this because there isn't a daemon running on this machine managing application priorities, like on Windows, maybe?

Comment: I have a feeling Pilot6 or Chili555 will be able to help you out.

Comment: Please edit your question to add: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2`

Comment: @chili555 Thank you for looking into the problem. I've just edited the question to add the output.

Comment: Is this a DSL connection, or something else? What MTU? What happens if you connect your computer directly to the modem, bypassing the switch/etc?

Comment: @heynnema Yes, a vDSL connection to be exact. The MTU is set to 1500 (by default). Connecting my machine to the modem/router directly doesn't seem to make any noticeable difference. I'd like to mention that connectivity worked perfectly fine on Windows without any configuration, except for installing the divers on the disk included with the motherboard (where the Ethernet card is part of), if that might help.

Comment: Yeah, the fact that Windows works won't really tell us much, as Windows does things differently. Without going through the entire testing process with you, with DSL you probably have to adjust your MTU to 1492.

Comment: ps: if you search here, or on Goggle, for "vdsl mtu" it'll show you the proper `ping` command to use for full testing of the MTU that you should use.

Comment: Changing the MTU value using `sudo ifconfig enp3s0 mtu 1492 up` doesn't seem to have any effect on the connectivity. The ping commands seem to give very inconsistent result. Sometimes a ping goes through (with a specific MTU), sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: 1492 may not be the correct value for your vDSL. Use the ping commands to properly size your MTU. You may also have to change your router's MTU... but use the ping command first. As long as you're getting fragmentation, the MTU is wrong. If memory serves me, you need to start at a low MTU and work your way up until it fragments, then your correct value is one back. Otherwise you'll get inconsistent results. Try starting at 1460.

Comment: ps: for new comments directed at me, please start with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema My ISP states that 1500 MTU is supported as maximum on their vDSL network. But I will try to find out what ping results in as you suggested in a minute.

Comment: Yes, that's because they don't want users going over the 1500 MTU and effecting bandwidth. Your actual value will/should be lower than 1500. 1492 is for standard DSL. vDSL probably requires something lower. The ping command will tell all :-)

Comment: @heynnema I've tried to change the MTU, but this doesn't seem to help anything. I'm still experiencing packet loss and other weird networking quirks. I did figure out however that `1492` seems to be the correct MTU value on my network. I've added output from another command to the question as I thought it might be useful.

Comment: @heynnema I just noticed that the network seems to be slightly faster than before, after changing the MTU, see http://www.speedtest.net/result/6022008932.png . There's still however, a lot of packet loss going on.

Comment: Did you also change the MTU value in your router? Do you have QOS enabled on your router, and is it properly set for your WAN speed?

Comment: @heynnema I can't change the router's MTU value, it's configured automatically through DSL and seems to be correct. QoS is enabled and configured properly. Prioritizing my machine doesn't seem to help. I have a FritzBox 7581 if that helps. The issue still presist even after trying various things. I'm quite sure it has something to do with the network card itself, and the interface with it to Linux. What could the problem be. Maybe it would be useful to list all properties (automatically) set on Windows, on which the card works fine? Maybe these settings can be applied to Linux?

Comment: @heynnema I've added output of a ping flood command to the bottom of the command output list. It shows that I'm loosing 48% of packets. I don't know what the acceptable loss rate is for floods, but 48% seems quite high. Also, the ethernet card is part of my MSI Z87-G45 (gaming) motherboard.

Comment: When you say "The card worked out of the box with a fresh installation, sort of." what do you mean? Did you replace the built-in alx driver in 16.10 with something else? Do a `modinfo alx | grep version`. Google "linux alx driver" and see if there's something better/newer.

Comment: ps: what is the router's MTU? Is it your (wireless) router, or belong to your ISP?

Comment: ps: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=alx

Comment: @heynnema Yes, it worked 'out of the box', I already had connectivity in the OS's installer. I did not install anything other than the OS itself (Ubuntu GNOME 16.10), no additional drivers were manually installed. The router does belong to my ISP indeed, and it's a quite recent one. I appended ALX's version to the command output, and I'll try to find a newer version as you suggested! I might try to modify the ALX module myself to see if tweaking things improves anything (I'm a programmer, yes).